# Removing events associated with an element

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I have 5 img tags like.

```
<img id="test-btn" src="image/btn1.png" onmouseover="this.src='image/btn2.png'" onmousedown="this.src='image/btn1.png'" onmouseup="this.src='image/btn2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='image/btn1.png'" onclick="uponClickingTestBtn()" style="heignt:15px;width:30px;">
```

When I click on one of the image tags, others should be disabled. I don't want even the events like onmouseover to happen on the image. Is it possible to remove the events associated with an element? I tried

```
$('#test-btn').filter("input,textarea,select,button").prop('disabled',true);
```

and

```
$('#test-btn :input').attr('disabled', true);
```

but did not work. How will I do this? I will also want to enable those img clicks later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to be in line to your code, you could do this:

```
$('#test-btn :input').attr('onmousedown', null);
$('#test-btn :input').attr('onmouseover', null);
$('#test-btn :input').attr('onclick', null);
$('#test-btn :input').attr('onmouseout', null);
$('#test-btn :input').attr('onmouseup', null);
```

however, consider not putting inline events, and go wtih jquery .on() witch has a function off() to remove events.

if you still go with the fisrt solution, you can reassign an event like so:

```
$('#test-btn :input').attr('onmouseover', "this.src='image/btn2.png'");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

NULL the function binding and it doesn't do anything anymore on the click. To be sure I've added a removal for the attribute inside the element too.

```
var button = document.getElementById('test-btn');
button.onmouseover = null;
button.removeAttribute('onmouseover');
```

In jQuery you can just `preventDefault` or return `false`. Sometimes people use both. Remember to return `false` at the end tho, if you want to still do actions inside the click, otherwise the function will "abort";

```
$('#test-btn').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    return false;
});
```